React version update issue
Greetings all so i have this old project which uses react 16 i wanted to update the react version to 18 . any advice on how i can upgrade it without breaking code . appreciate all the help i can get thanks .
My **package.json **file
{
  "name": "blueclerk-react-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@casl/ability": "^6.5.0",
    "@casl/react": "^3.1.0",
    "@date-io/date-fns": "1.x",
    "@date-io/moment": "^2.10.6",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.0",
    "@material-ui/data-grid": "4.0.0-alpha.35",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.9.1",
    "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.57",
    "@material-ui/pickers": "^3.2.10",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.11.16",
    "@opentelemetry/api": "^1.4.0",
    "@opentelemetry/context-zone": "^1.9.1",
    "@opentelemetry/exporter-trace-otlp-http": "^0.35.1",
    "@opentelemetry/instrumentation": "^0.35.1",
    "@opentelemetry/instrumentation-document-load": "^0.31.1",
    "@opentelemetry/instrumentation-user-interaction": "^0.32.1",
    "@opentelemetry/instrumentation-xml-http-request": "^0.35.1",
    "@opentelemetry/resources": "^1.9.1",
    "@opentelemetry/sdk-trace-web": "^1.9.1",
    "@opentelemetry/semantic-conventions": "^1.9.1",
    "@opentelemetry/tracing": "^0.24.0",
    "@opentelemetry/web": "^0.24.0",
    "@react-google-maps/api": "^2.5.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.3",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "@types/classnames": "^2.2.10",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.0",
    "@types/lodash.debounce": "^4.0.6",
    "@types/lodash.groupby": "^4.6.7",
    "@types/node": "^14.0.13",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.36",
    "@types/react-date-range": "^1.4.3",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.8",
    "@types/react-geocode": "^0.2.0",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.9",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.5",
    "@types/react-swipeable-views": "^0.13.0",
    "@types/react-table": "^7.0.22",
    "@types/react-text-mask": "^5.4.6",
    "@types/styled-components": "^5.1.2",
    "@types/validator": "^13.1.0",
    "apexcharts": "^3.36.0",
    "axios": "^0.20.0",
    "classnames": "^2.2.6",
    "date-fns": "^2.15.0",
    "env-cmd": "^10.1.0",
    "formik": "^2.1.5",
    "google-map-react": "^2.1.3",
    "immutable": "^4.0.0-rc.12",
    "intuit-oauth": "^3.0.2",
    "lodash.debounce": "^4.0.8",
    "lodash.groupby": "^4.6.0",
    "moment": "^2.27.0",
    "notistack": "^1.0.0",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-apexcharts": "^1.4.0",
    "react-date-range": "^1.4.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-geocode": "^0.2.1",
    "react-hot-loader": "^4.12.21",
    "react-material-ui-carousel": "v2",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1",
    "react-social-login": "^3.4.9",
    "react-swipeable-views": "^0.13.9",
    "react-table": "^7.5.0",
    "react-text-mask": "^5.4.3",
    "react-to-print": "^2.14.7",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-actions": "^2.6.5",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.8",
    "redux-saga": "^1.1.3",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "rounded-bar-chartjs": "^1.0.2",
    "sass": "^1.77.6",
    "scoped-css-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "socket.io-client": "^4.0.0",
    "spinkit": "^2.0.1",
    "styled-components": "^5.1.1",
    "supercluster": "^7.1.5",
    "typescript": "^3.9.5",
    "use-supercluster": "^0.4.0",
    "validator": "^13.1.1",
    "yarn": "^1.22.10",
    "yup": "^0.29.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts --openssl-legacy-provider start",
    "build": "export SET NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider && react-scripts build",
    "build:staging": "env-cmd -f .env.staging react-scripts build",
    "build:test": "env-cmd -f .env.test react-scripts build",
    "build:release": "env-cmd -f .env.release react-scripts build",
    "build:production": "env-cmd -f .env.production react-scripts build",
    "lint": "node ./node_modules/eslint/bin/eslint",
    "lint-src": "npm run lint -- src/**/*.ts{,x}"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
   ">0.2%",
  "not dead",
  "not op_mini all"
],
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/google-map-react": "^2.1.0",
    "@types/immutable": "^3.8.7",
    "@types/redux-actions": "^2.6.1",
    "@types/redux-saga": "^0.10.5",
    "@types/styled-components": "^5.1.2",
    "@types/yup": "^0.29.7",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^3.9.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^3.9.1",
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.0.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.10.0",
    "eslint-import-resolver-node": "^0.3.3",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.20.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.2.3",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.19.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^1.7.0",
    "husky": "^4.2.5",
    "pre-commit": "^1.2.2",
    "prettier": "^2.0.5"
  },
  "pre-commit": [
    "lint-src"
  ]
}


this are my deps please do help me out because updating it to even 17 caused a lot of errors.
i tried to update it but got loads of error when upgrading to 18.
ERROR in src/app/pages/customer/view-more/view-more.tsx:230:5
TS2769: No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(to: To, options?: NavigateOptions): void', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '{ state: any; key: string; pathname: string; search: string; hash: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'To'.
      Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'state' does not exist in type 'Partial<Path>'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(delta: number): void', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '{ state: any; key: string; pathname: string; search: string; hash: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.
    228 |     };
    229 |
  > 230 |     navigate({
        |     ^^^^^^^^^^
  > 231 |       ...location,
        | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  > 232 |       state: {
        | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  > 233 |         ...location.state,
        | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  > 234 |         curTab: newValue
        | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  > 235 |       }
        | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  > 236 |     });
        | ^^^^^^^
    237 |     setCurTab(newValue);
    238 |   };
    239 |







